# Создание новостного приложения для мобилок

Tags: django, postgresql, react-native

Написал маленький фронт на React-Native для новостного приложения, теперь хочу модифицировать его так, чтобы через комп можно было добавлять/редактировать новости, а в мобилки они появлялись. Есть идея воспользоваться Django, но не особо понимаю принцип работы бэка.

Мне нужно создать базу на postgre + админ-панель, с которой будет идти создание/редактирование карточек? Есть какие-либо статьи по этому?

Comment: Думаю, тут есть почти все, что вам нужно https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site

Comment: админка уже есть в django. по поводу бека, возможно заинтересует Drango Rest Framework